# Pywinauto script compiled as exe using Pyinstaller executes locally but not remotely from the cmd line using PSEXEC

Tags: python, pyinstaller, psexec, pywinauto

I have a requirement whereby the navigation and control of a legacy application has to be automated - this automated method, packaged as a script, would need to be deployed via SCCM to our user base.

After some research, I've decided to use Python's PywinAuto module to achieve my goal.

I've managed to create a script that automates all the GUI steps as required and I've also packaged this script as an exe using the Pyinstaller module, but the issue i'm now having is the following: when running locally on both Windows 7 and Windows 10 machines, the exe executes successful.  However, when triggering the exe remotely through either SCCM or PSEXEC, the exe fails to execute.

I've also wrapped the exe in a powershell script, but the same thing occurs when executing the script via PSEXEC or SCCM.

I'm running PSEXEC as the System user, which has full admin rights. The SCCM user has full admin rights aswell.

*This is the Pyinstaller example script that I packaged into an exe, just for testing purpose:*

```
from __future__ import print_function
import logging
from pywinauto import actionlogger
from pywinauto import Application

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--log", help = "enable logging", type=str, required = False)
args = parser.parse_args()

actionlogger.enable()
logger = logging.getLogger('pywinauto')
if args.log:
    logger.handlers[0] = logging.FileHandler(args.log)

app = Application(backend='uia').start(r'mspaint.exe')
dlg = app.window(title_re='.* - Paint')


dlg.close()
```

*When running the exe locally from the the command line, the following appears indicating successful execution:*

> c:\Temp>pywinauto_test 2019-05-11 07:47:14,215 INFO: Started
>   mspaint.exe application. 2019-05-11 07:47:14,344 INFO: Closed window
>   "Untitled - Paint"

*When running remotely through psexec, the following appears:*

> C:\Temp>pywinauto_test.exe 2019-05-11 07:29:38,221 INFO: Started
>   mspaint.exe application. [ 5516] Failed to executC:\Temp>e script
>   Pywinautopaint Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 256, in
>   __resolve_control   File "site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Pywinautopaint.py", line
>   59, in    File "site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line
>   378, in **getattribute**   File
>   "site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 259, in
>   __resolve_control   File "site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes   File
>   "site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 201, in __get_ctrl
>   File "site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in
>   find_element pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title_re':
>   '.* - Paint', 'backend': 'uia', 'process': 2844}

Answer (score 0):

All known methods to run GUI automation remotely are listed in the [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html). It's not specific to PyInstaller or other py2exe-like tools. Mostly it's OS Windows restrictions and RDP features that can be workarounded by several ways.

Also `ElementNotFoundError` is often raised when default timeout to find window (5 sec.) is insufficient. For example, if remote virtual machine is slow. This might be unrelated to common remote execution problems.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Vasily. What I've found is, the process does start but no GUI displays - so it would seem as if it is indeed a security restriction.

Comment: Are you running the remote job as a service?

Comment: Nope, it's not run as a service.